# Java JRadioButton continuously adds double to variable when selecting back and forth

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jradiobutton

When I select radio button "six", it adds 6.00 to variable "total", and then when I select radio button "twelve" it adds 8.00 to variable "total". I'm trying to get it so when I select button six for example, it will add 6.00 only and not add 8.00 when I tap on twelve.

```
class Size extends JPanel
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  JLabel length = new JLabel("Select Sandwich Size");
  JPanel sizePanel = new JPanel();
  JRadioButton six = new JRadioButton("6 Inch"); 
  JRadioButton twelve = new JRadioButton("12 Inch");
  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

  public Size()
  {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(length, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    sizePanel.add(six);
    sizePanel.add(twelve);
    add(sizePanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    group.add(six);
    group.add(twelve);

    //Radio button listener which adds size cost to variable total
    class SizeListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        if (six.isSelected()) total += 6.00;
        else if (twelve.isSelected()) total += 8.00;

      }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new SizeListener();
    six.addActionListener(listener);
    twelve.addActionListener(listener);

  }

}
```

Comment: Please explain the problem in greater detail. It sounds like you need to recalculate all numbers when the radio button is pressed, but I can't tell for sure without more information and code, preferably a [mcve]. Also are you binding the JRadioButtons to a ButtonGroup object?

Comment: Just added the whole class, the variable total is defined in a different public class

Comment: When i select button six it adds 6.00 to total, and then when I select button twelve it adds 8.00 to total making the total = 14.00, whereas the total should only be able to equal 6.00 or 8.00

Comment: I don't see the total variable anywhere in your code above. Is this part of a larger class? Please post a [mcve], code we can run, including a main method and a GUI (JFrame).

Comment: remove this total += 6.00 with total = 6.00.

Comment: removing += and replacing with = worked, thanks!

Comment: @Liam: not for long. Not when you make your sandwich slightly more complex -- including adding or removing other components.

Comment: This has already happened, there is another class which gives yes and no options to add cheese for 1.00, and you cannot make total = 1.00.

Comment: Make your program more M-V-C (model-view-controller -- Google this) like. Create a non-gui Sandwich class, and have your ActionListener change its state -- here its length -- and then let the Sandwich class object calculate its own totals based on its state -- meaning its length, its contents, its type of bread,...etc.